# Cannot configure doCatch block in Camel 3.8.0 XML

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel

Since Camel 3.8.0, I'm not able to configure a doCatch block in XML as follows:

```
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring https://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <route>
        <from uri="direct:start"  />
        <doTry>
            <to uri="log:try" />
            <doCatch>
                <exception>java.lang.RuntimeException</exception>
                <to uri="log:catch" />
            </doCatch>
        </doTry>
    </route>
</routes>
```

I'm getting

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This doCatch should have a doTry as its parent on DoCatch[ [class java.lang.RuntimeException] -> [To[log:catch]]]
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.CatchReifier.createProcessor(CatchReifier.java:50) ~[camel-core-reifier-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.CatchReifier.createProcessor(CatchReifier.java:30) ~[camel-core-reifier-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.createProcessor(ProcessorReifier.java:812) ~[camel-core-reifier-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.TryReifier.createProcessor(TryReifier.java:46) ~[camel-core-reifier-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.makeProcessor(ProcessorReifier.java:835) ~[camel-core-reifier-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.ProcessorReifier.addRoutes(ProcessorReifier.java:576) ~[camel-core-reifier-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.doCreateRoute(RouteReifier.java:236) ~[camel-core-reifier-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Which, as far as I understand, means that the doCatch block is missing its parent (doTry). When I debug, the parent is indeed null.

Am I missing something or is this a bug or changed API? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in this version of Apache Camel (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-16534) which was fixed in 3.10.0.